# UNCalendarNotificationTrigger not initiating

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification, timedelay, uncalendarnotificationtrigger

Okay - I am totally frustrated with this piece of code right now and ready to give up! Basically when simulating to either Simulator or actual device I get the requestAuthorisation to work no problem but the trigger does not initiate ever. I have followed several guys online and their code worked with ease! When I use a button to initiate a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger it works but that is not what I want. Currently testing in iOS 14.3 as target for build. Rest of the App builds no problem. What am I doing wrong?! Cannot help but think that somewhere along the line of trying to get it to work I might have damaged something in info.plist or similar?! I have tested to repeat the trigger and not to repeat but neither works.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //NOTIFICATIONS
        // Step 1 - Ask the use for permission to notify
        let randVerseCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        randVerseCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Yay - request authorisation worked!")
            } else {
                print ("D'oH - request Authorisation did not work!")
            }
        }
        // Step 2 - Create the Notification Content
        let randVerseContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        randVerseContent.title = "Random Reference"
        randVerseContent.body = "Random Verse"
        randVerseContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        // Step 3 - Create the trigger for the notification by delay
        let randVerseDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(30)
        let randVerseDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: randVerseDate)
        let randVerseTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: randVerseDateComponents, repeats: true)
        // Step 4 - Creating the request
        let randVerseUUIDString = UUID().uuidString
        let randVerseRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: randVerseUUIDString, content: randVerseContent, trigger: randVerseTrigger)
        // Step 5 - Register the request
        randVerseCenter.add(randVerseRequest) { (error) in
            if let error = error{
                print (error.localizedDescription)
            }
            //Check the error parameter and handle any errors
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting more details, I guess I know why you still don't see the notifications being delivered. I'm making it in another answer to not have it too long, but I'll keep [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65601887/564532/#65601887) for reference.
Maybe you were waiting for the notification with the application in foreground? I'll refer to another part of the documentation:

[Scheduling and Handling Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)
On the section about *Handling Notifications When Your App Is in the Foreground*:

> If a notification arrives while your app is in the foreground, you can
> silence that notification or tell the system to continue to display
> the notification interface. *The system silences notifications for
> foreground apps by **default***, delivering the notification’s data
> directly to your app...

So, if that's the case, you must implement a delegate for `UNUserNotificationCenter`.
I suggest you something like this, where on AppDelegate you assign the delegate for `UNUserNotificationCenter` since documentation says it must be done before application finishes launching:

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }

    // Rest of your code on AppDelegate...
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // Here we actually handle the notification
        print("Notification received with identifier \(notification.request.identifier)")
        // So we call the completionHandler telling that the notification should display a banner and play the notification sound - this will happen while the app is in foreground
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
    }
}
```

On the view controller you have handling the notification authorization and request registration, you could do it like this:

```swift
class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    static let notificationAuthorizedNotification = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationAuthorizedNotification")
    let randVerseCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // We call this method when we know that the user granted permission, so we know we can then make notification requests
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotificationAuthorization), name: NotificationsViewController.notificationAuthorizedNotification, object: nil)
        
        randVerseCenter.getNotificationSettings { [weak self] settings in
            // We check current settings and asks for permission if not granted before
            if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                // Step 1 - Ask the use for permission to notify
                self?.randVerseCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in
                    if granted {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationsViewController.notificationAuthorizedNotification, object: nil)
                        print("Yay - request authorisation worked!")
                    } else {
                        print ("D'oH - request Authorisation did not work!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        // We stop listening to those notifications here
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    @objc
    func handleNotificationAuthorization() {
        // Step 2 - Create the Notification Content
        let randVerseContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        randVerseContent.title = "Random Reference"
        randVerseContent.body = "Random Verse"
        randVerseContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        // Step 3 - Create the trigger for the notification by delay
        let randVerseDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(30)
        let randVerseDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: randVerseDate)
        let randVerseTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: randVerseDateComponents, repeats: true)
        // Step 4 - Creating the request
        let randVerseUUIDString = UUID().uuidString
        let randVerseRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: randVerseUUIDString, content: randVerseContent, trigger: randVerseTrigger)
        // Step 5 - Register the request
        randVerseCenter.add(randVerseRequest) { (error) in
            if let error = error{
                print (error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Successfully registered notification with id \(randVerseUUIDString) at every second \(randVerseDateComponents.second!) of a minute")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might still have older notifications scheduled since your code was requesting them at the `viewDidLoad` and maybe you didn't remove them or delete the app.
You can check the pending notifications using this on your `viewDidLoad` for example:

```swift
        randVerseCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests() { requests in
            for request in requests {
                guard let trigger = request.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger else { return }
                print("Notification registered with id \(request.identifier) is schedulled for \(trigger.nextTriggerDate()?.description ?? "(not schedulled)")")
            }
        }
```

And use `randVerseCenter` to remove them by their identifiers or remove all of them.

Comment: Many thanks @Jobert!! This worked perfectly!! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how the trigger was created. We can look at the documentation for `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` to get more understanding:

> Create a UNCalendarNotificationTrigger object when you want to
> schedule the delivery of a local notification at the specified date
> and time. You specify the temporal information using an
> NSDateComponents object, which lets you specify only the time values
> that matter to you. The system uses the provided information to
> determine the next date and time that matches the specified
> information.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger

So, you use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` when you want to create a trigger to match the date components. The code below will create a trigger which will deliver a notification every day at 8:30 in the morning, because the `.hour` and the `.minute` components were specified:

```swift
    var date = DateComponents()
    date.hour = 8
    date.minute = 30 
    // This trigger will match these two components - hour and minute
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
```

In your case, you created a trigger using all of the components of a date (year, month, dat, hour, minute, second):

```swift
let randVerseDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: randVerseDate)
```

And that makes it an impossible condition to repeat the trigger - because there won't be another year 2021 - so it will not be triggered.

You need to think how you want this notification to be triggered. If your intention is to deliver a notification on the same second counting from a specific time, then you must use only the `.second` date component:

```swift
let randVerseDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: randVerseDate)
```

Let's say `randVerseDate` is something like **2021-01-06-20:01:35**, and we use the line of code above. Then this will trigger the notification every minute when the clock reaches **35** seconds: **20:02:35**, then **20:03:35**, then **20:04:35**, and so on...

Comment: Many many thanks for your help @Jobert. I tried what you had stated to just remove all of the components from the dateComponents array except .second. However, I still have not success. I had also tried at an earlier stage to implement the code that you had mentioned earlier - i.e. an exact time where the notification would repeat every day but this also does not work. This method would also meet my goals but I could not get it to work. I read in a forum that a repeats: true of less than 1 minute would not work but even anything >61 secs will not work for me. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I keep thinking the code is fine because when I run it the Registering of the request works (added a bit of code to return the uuidString) just to check. I think I have definitely done something in my Xcode software somewhere. If I run the code even in a completely blank project in the viewDidLoad with nothing else it does not work for me. Authorisation works fine but the notification never comes through @Jobert. Thanks again!